# Installed Python on Windows 8, getting syntax errors on simple statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

If I just start python from the command line with `python` then run something like `print "test"`, I get a syntax error. Statements like `1+1` work fine. Is something wrong with my new Python installation?

Comment: Have you installed version 3.x ? Try `print("test")`

Comment: I did install 3.x, what else has changed haha, I guess I am more familiar with 2.x.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have 2.7 installed any more, my friend.

this might be helpful

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3